# cannot change output format in gstreamer

Tags: video, gstreamer

I am using a camera which supports 1080 and 720p videos at both 30 and 25 frames per second. I can get the webcam to stream with the following gstreamer command on my ARM board

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! "video/x-raw, width=1920, 
height=1080, format=(string)YUY2, framerate=30/1" ! xvimagesink sync=false -e
```

However, I find that I cannot change any of these parameters. For example, if I change the `framerate` to `25/1`, I get the error:

```
error: streaming task paused, reason not-negotiated (-4)
```

I wonder if this may be a hardware issue or am I using gstreamer incorrectly and there might be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To know details you can look at the debug logs, GST_DEBUG=3,v4l*:6 should give you quite some information.

But in summary, the problem is that your camera driver does not want to provide GStreamer something with those caps and e.g. 25fps instead of 30fps. If you change other things, it might also be a problem with the sink not accepting those caps btw, you might want to put a videoconvert and videoscale in front of xvimagesink to prevent that.

Comment: Thanks for that. I did the videoconvert and video scale and that did not change the behaviour. I have a feeling this has something to do with the camera and there might be some other mechanism needs to be set for changing its capabilities. I need to see if I can dig up some documentation online for this.