# gstreamer udpsrc rescale window

Tags: resize, gstreamer

I'm trying to use Gstreamer-1.0 to send my screen thought udp and resizing it.
(Client sends data to server)

Here is the client :

```
     gst-launch-1.0 ximagesrc use-damage=false xname=/usr/lib/torcs/torcs-bin 
! videoconvert ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=800,height=600 ! vp8enc 
! rtpvp8pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5100
```

And the server :

```
    gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5100 
caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)VP8-DRAFT-IETF-01, payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)2990747501, clock-base=(uint)275641083, seqnum-base=(uint)34810" 
! rtpvp8depay ! vp8dec ! autovideosink
```

I want to rescale the output video but I didn't succeed.
I tried to add ",width=...,length=..." in caps 
OR
use "! videoconvert ! videoscale ! video/x-raw ,width=600,height=300, framerate=30/1" which worked for simple streams like

```
  gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src \
    ! videoconvert ! videoscale \
    ! video/x-raw ,width=600,height=300, framerate=30/1 \
    ! autovideosink
```

There may be 2 solutions :

- I'm using the right things at the wrong place.
- I'm on the wrong way.

Thanks for your help,
Have a nice day !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that using " ! video/x-raw ,width=600,height=300, framerate=30/1 \" sometimes gives me an error. After some investigations, I've found a recent post about it :

[cannot change output format in gstreamer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35879746/cannot-change-output-format-in-gstreamer)

Hope it'll help.